# Export project in SVN into zip / rar file

Tags: svn

I have a project that I was working on last year, that was left in my university's svn repository. I'm currently on a machine without TortoiseSVN or Eclipse and would like to simply have the project as a zip or rar file (no need to work on it).

It has been a while since I worked with svn and I can't really be downloading IDE's and stuff on this machine. Would anybody be able to give me a quick guide on how I can achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you an access to svn repo? If so, you can use the `svn checkout` from commandline and get the working copy of your code

Answer (score 0):

Just run `svn export URL-to-the-project` and you will get an export of the project.

Read [SVNBook | `svn export` command line reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) for more information.